# How do I stop dmesg messages about previously used NFS client mount?

Tags: linux, nfs, dmesg, unmounting, nfsv4

In Linux 5.8.0, NFSv4 client was in use for some time, then server gone away from network, then I `umount -f -l`-ed it away.

Typically I expect NFS-related messages to go away from kernel log, but now I still see periodic

```
[3287933.728975] nfs: server ... not responding, timed out
[3287941.429039] nfs: server ... not responding, timed out
[3287949.876782] nfs: server ... not responding, timed out
[3287953.908900] nfs: server ... not responding, timed out
[3287957.556741] nfs: server ... not responding, timed out
[3287963.124716] nfs: server ... not responding, timed out
```

How do I make Linux kernel leave those NFS things in the past and continue normally (without a reboot, obviously)? I don't even see this mount in `cat /proc/*/mounts | sort` anymore.

---

There is an uninterruptible (disk) sleep process that has no memory associated with it (as if with zombie processes) with the name in stat that is beginning of IPv6 address of the NFS server that were used for the mount.

When I added that IP address to `lo`, dmesg messages changed to repeated `NFS: state manager: check lease failed on NFSv4 server <IPv6 address here> with error 13`. After I stopped local NFS server, messages changed back to `nfs: server <the address> not responding, timed out`. I still see periodic connection attempts to that address.

---

After identifying and partially disposing of hung leftover processes that was holding opened file handles there are `lsof -N` now completes without hanging and only two D-state processes left: `mpv` without memory of FDs and that mysterious IPv6-address-named process, both seemingly not affected by `kill -9`.

Comment: Does `lsof -N` show any open files at or under that NFS mount point?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick, It got stuck in uninterruptible sleep. There are two uninterruptible processes now: `lsof` and a strange process with a trimmed IPv6 address as a name.

Comment: The messages are still flowing.